# How to increase the memory heap size on IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, heap-memory

I want to allocate around 1GB of heap size, but I can't seem to figure it out.

How to do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use **Help** | **Edit Custom VM Options…**

[image: VM Options]

An editor will open automatically for the right `.vmoptions` file, adjust the value of `-Xmx`, save and restart IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: editor]

Check these documents from IntelliJ IDEA knowledge base for more details:

- [Configuring JVM options and platform properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869)
- [The JVM could not be started. The main method may have thrown an exception](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241105).

Answers below suggest to edit `.vmoptions` file directly inside the application installation directory. Please note that it's not recommended since it will cause conflicts during patch updates. The method above creates a copy of the file in the [CONFIG](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory and your IDE installation remains intact.

Also be aware of the 32-bit [address space limit on Windows](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241105) which makes it hard to use heap sizes higher than `750m`. Should you need to use larger heap, make sure to [switch to the 64-bit JVM first](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879), otherwise IDE may crash on start or start to crash randomly during work.

Comment: Important to note that there is a 32bit and 64bit version of the config.

Comment: This is a good method but not always effective. This method increases heap for the IDE but not for the other java processes the IDE runs in the background. I ran into this when copying data between DB sources and kept getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space `. Overriding `.vmoptions` file next to `idea64.exe` was the solution. The background JVM's get it from there.

Answer (score 21):

go to that path "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions"
 and change size to -Xmx512m

```
  -Xms128m
  -Xmx512m
  -XX:MaxPermSize=250m
  -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
  -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
  -ea
  -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

hope its will work

Comment: When I change it I have this error code -4. What should I do here?

Comment: try to restart system

Comment: Using IntelliJ 13.1.2, restarting doesn't fix error code.

Comment: I got error code -4 when i increase -Xmx above 1024, so seems maximum value is 1024. Tried with Intellij 13.1.2

Comment: Intellij uses two JVMs. The the accepted answer is for your JAVA development/run configurations, this is for your IDE

Answer (score 15):

For **64-bit Windows**, make sure to run idea in 64 bit mode(**idea64.exe**) and change settings in "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\bin\**idea64.exe.vmoptions**" file. 
These settings works fine for me

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=700m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
```

Comment: this setting solved my issue on Mac OSX running pycharm.

Answer (score 5):

For developers who use `Ubuntu`, following will help to **increase heap size** in InteliJ Idea. Following versions are used by myself at the moment.

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit)
- InteliJ IDEA 2016.3.4

Go to the location where the IDE is installed and find the following file. (In my case it as follows)

```
/home/abcde/Softwares/idea-IU-163.12024.16/bin
```

Then select the **idea64.vmoptions**  file and edit it.

Remove default configuration and paste the below mentioned.

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=700m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
```

Now restart the IDE and changes should reflect the IDE environment.

Worked for me to overcome Java heap size related issues.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily increase memory heap from IntelliJ IDEA version 2019.2 by using IDE main menu `Help | Change Memory Settings`.

Please check this document for details: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html

Answer (score 5):

If you use JetBrains Toolbox, then memory changes must be set inside it:

1. Go to the app settings in the toolbox list
2. Change *Memory heap size* option within **Configuration** section

Otherwise all the changes in the IDE itself or inside vmoptions file just don't apply.

[image: Click Settings icon of the correspoinding IDE]

[image: Change heap size]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what others have added, should the error persist try this

[image: increase the memory heap size_0]

[image: increase the memory heap size_1]

[image: increase the memory heap size_2]

> *basically put what you want(as others have pointed out) in your **`run-config`**'s vm options and apply*

Comment: The font choice :)

Comment:  awful… I agree

Comment: This was the only solution that worked on Ubuntu 20 with Jetbrains Toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check your environment variables also. Mine was not updating until I changed my _JAVA_OPTIONS value from -Xmx512m to -Xmx2048m.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below version of Intellij, and simply u can just click on

**Help => Change Memory Settings**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the play button then modify run configuration then build and run modify option select add vm option this will add a text box now give the values like:
-Xmx7g