# How should I set the memory for IntelliJ 14?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just upgraded my IntelliJ to 14.0.3. But there's always an Out Of Memory dialog popped up to ask me to set the memory.

Following is my settings:
[image]

I thought it's enough. But the dialog shows from time to time, and sometimes, it's not responding that I have to shutdown it.

How should I set this for IntelliJ 14? Any ideas?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Open Intellij IDE's **vmoptions** file

**For Mac Users**

`Help | Edit Custom VM Options...`

or

`Library > Preferences > Idea<YourVersion> > idea.vmoptions`

**For Window (32bit) Users**

C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA `<your_version>`\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions

**For Window (64bit) Users**

C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA `<your_version>`\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions

and setup it's memory as you wish. Below is sample settings for **2GB**

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Hopefully this help.

Comment: I can't startup my IntelliJ if I set -Xmx to 2048M, my computer has 8 GB memory.

Comment: Here is useful questions for your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221725/how-to-increase-the-memory-heap-size-on-intellij-idea-12  , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578062/how-to-increase-ide-memory-limit-in-intellij-idea-on-mac

Comment: under Windows: "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions"

Comment: Under Windows it could be either of the followings, depending on which installation (x86, x64) you use:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.4\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions"

Comment: `Help | Edit Custom VM Options` works on Windows too. IntelliJ 2018.2

Answer (score 10):

I have allocated 4 GB to intelliJ 14 on windows 7. My settings in idea64.exe.vmoptions are :

-Xms4608m
-Xmx4608m
-Xmn2g
-Xss128k
-XX:MaxPermSize=1536m
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=20

Comment: for the hardware grammar police, "4GB" is `4096m` (4 * 1GB = 4 * 1024MB)

Comment: Was trying to commit but failed after 20 minutes from out of memory error. Did the above and the commit was processed almost instantly. Thanks!

Comment: The -Xmx setting also seems to work on Linux (Mint 17.3), and solved the stupid memory popup problem. This was driving me crazy. I even switched which Java IDEA boots from (it's bundled now in Linux) to the latest and greatest JRE and it was still slow.

Comment: for WebStorm you want to find the webstorm.vmoptions file located in WebStorm.app/Contents/bin/webstorm.vmoptions

Answer (score 4):

You can set IntelliJ IDEA's memory settings *and* your application's memory settings in the following places:

**IDEA's vmoptions file:**

Under Windows it could be either of the followings, depending on which installation (x86, x64) you use:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
  2016.3.4\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions
- C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA
  2016.3.4\bin\idea64.exe.vmoptions

**VM Options in the Run/Debug Configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you still see this popup frequently even with high memory allocated, try:

> File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Comment: Seems it worked for a little time. Then the dialog shows again.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the nature of the error. One thing to try is using idea64.exe instead of idea.exe.

If this doesn't help, please contact JetBrains by filing an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newissue and attach your log there (Help | Show log).