# How to increase HEAP memory for Webstorm 2016 on MAC OS X

Tags: webstorm

Webstorm keeps hanging. I followed the following steps.
Clicked on Help > Edit Custom VM Options

Change the settings to:

```
-Xms750m
-Xmx2084m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

However, this has not prevented webstorm from hanging.

Comment: Freezing is not necessary caused by memory issues. If it stops responding, try getting thread dumps (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899-Getting-a-thread-dump-when-IDE-hangs-and-doesn-t-respond) and provide them to support

Comment: using suggestions from here.. seems to be working for webstorm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760415/how-should-i-set-the-memory-for-intellij-14

Comment: did you get outOfMemory error popup?