# How to change InteliJ Java max heap size?

Tags: java

I tried changing max heap size through compiler settings. Also i tried changing it through idea64.exe.vmoptions with property -Xmx8G, but it still didint work. Any ideas how i can fix heap size error?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase the memory heap size on IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221725/how-to-increase-the-memory-heap-size-on-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of Xmx by editing the idea64.exe.vmoption

Or

Help-> Edit Custom Vm option